# LWP::UserAgent change SSL implementation

Tags: perl, ssl

I want to use LWP::UserAgent to send some requests over HTTPS. There is this sentence in the ssl_opts section in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ssl_opts)

> Other options can be set and are processed directly by the SSL Socket
>   implementation in use. See IO::Socket::SSL or Net::SSL for details.

I have installed both modules on my machine and I think I have some problems because of it.

How can I find out which one is in use and how to change it to use the other module?

Comment: "I think I have some problems because of it. " You will need to give more details on that. So, see [mcve] and show the code you run and the exact errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out which one is in use

If you look at `LWP::UserAgent` documentation it says you need to install `LWP::Protocol::https` module to have support for `https://` URIs.

If you look at this module in turn you see that it does use the `Net::HTTP` distribution, into which you find a `HTTPS.pm` module (see it online at https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/Net-HTTP-6.18/lib/Net/HTTPS.pm) where at the beginning you can clearly see that, except if overriden, it first start to try using `IO::Socket::SSL` and next only searches for `Net::SSL`.

See:

```
elsif ($IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION) {
    $SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = "IO::Socket::SSL"; # it was already loaded
}
elsif ($Net::SSL::VERSION) {
    $SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = "Net::SSL";
}
```

If they are not loaded yet, it tries to load them, in the same order:

```
eval { require IO::Socket::SSL; };
if ($@) {
    my $old_errsv = $@;
    eval {
        require Net::SSL;  # from Crypt-SSLeay
    };
    if ($@) {
        $old_errsv =~ s/\s\(\@INC contains:.*\)/)/g;
        die $old_errsv . $@;
    }
    $SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = "Net::SSL";
}
else {
    $SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = "IO::Socket::SSL";
}
```

So, in short, `IO::Socket::SSL` has full precedence.

Inside your program, after having used `LWP::UserAgent` you can use the `$Net::HTTPS::SSL_SOCKET_CLASS` variable to know which class has been used for HTTPS operations.

> how to change it to use the other module?

If you read the beginning of the code you will see:

```
elsif ($SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = $ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS}) {
    unless ($SSL_SOCKET_CLASS =~ /^(IO::Socket::SSL|Net::SSL)\z/) {
        die "Bad socket class [$SSL_SOCKET_CLASS]";
    }
    eval "require $SSL_SOCKET_CLASS";
    die $@ if $@;
}
```

which means that before everything above if the environment has a variable `PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS` defined, then its value is used as a class to do operations, if its name is either `IO::Socket::SSL` or `Net::SSL`.

So, either set it in your environment before starting your program that uses `LWP::UserAgent` or do something like that in your program:

```
BEGIN {
    $ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = 'Net::SSL';
}
```

This needs to happen **before** you do `use LWP::UserAgent;`